# How to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TO MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS IN SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2008-express

How to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (in 24 hours format) to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss (in 24 hours format? **I am using Sql Server 2008.**

```
Given Date Format: 2017-12-18 18:16:49 - Its in DateTime format
Required Date Format: 18-12-2017 18:16:49
```

Comment: You can use `format()`.

Comment: 1. Tag the Sql Server version you are using. 2. Provide the data type of the column you are querying.

Comment: Also, change your question from MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS. No way the required date format matches what you had asked.

Comment: It can be done as follows:

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14)

Comment: Where possible, I would format a datetime data type at the consumer / presentation end, not within the database query

Comment: @Sandeep.. I tried your approach, but the result is in this format - '18/12/2017 13:45:29'. I require '18-12-2017 13:45:29'

Comment: Is your column an actual `datetime` or `datetime2` type or is it of type `varchar`?

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103),'/','-') + ' ' + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14)`

Comment: `REPLACE` slashes with hyphens.

Comment: @MdKamranAzam Update the query to: select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) + ' ' + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14) And it will replace the forward slash with the hyphen.

Comment: Thanks to all. I got the solution from @Tanveer Singh Bhatia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Would work in Older SQL Server Versions Also, Converted to datetime first if it's **VARCHAR** otherwise you can skip that conversion.

```
SELECT convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'2017-12-18 18:16:49'),105) + ' ' + 
convert(varchar(8),convert(datetime,'2017-12-18 18:16:49'),14);
```

Use this [Link](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) as Reference for Date & Time conversion Formats

Comment: Thanks Tanveer. Exactly what I was finding.

Comment: You Are Welcome, Do use the Links provided for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2017-12-18 18:16:49' AS datetime) , 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Getting an error 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Severity 15 State 10

Comment: @MdKamranAzam i think using lower version sql server 2012

Comment: @MdKamranAzam, you should tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using as the best solution will vary depending on available features.

Comment: @Sreenu131. I am using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2017-12-18 18:16:49'

SELECT FORMAT(@date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice not change directly in SQL formate, instead you could change your php code where query fetch the date data

for example you could assign your $yourDate object to new dateTime, and use formate function to define the date format:

```
<?php
$yourDate = new DateTime();
$timestring = $yourDate->format('m-d-Y h:i:s');
echo $timestring;
```

the output will be: 05-18-2018 05:00:34

You could take reference [in this older discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

This will prevent some bug error might be occurred if your data table has some other date format relative to, and also it is more useful once you need to have change the date format again

Hope this will be help